# Normalize a matrix

Tags: matrices

What algorithm would I use to normalize a matrix?  I know there are different definitions of matrix normalization.  In my case given matrix $A$, find Anorm such that $(Anorm)'Anorm = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.  In my case, $A$ is not square.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for the nearest matrix to $A$ that has orthonormal columns. This problem is known as the Orthogonal Procrustes Problem (OPP) and has an explicit solution $A_o = UV^*$, where $A = U\Sigma V^*$ is the singular value decomposition of $A$.

Comment: If A is not singular, can I just use A(-1)?

Comment: No because $A^{-1}$ does not satisfy the equation you have written

Comment: Thanks.  I'll investigate SVD.